# Intel HAXM doesn't run on AMD and I've turned off Hyper-V

Tags: android-studio, svm, amd-processor, haxm

[image]

[image]

Event Viewer says there are no Hyper-V operations, and they're off in services. I turned on SVM in BIOS, but still, it gives me an error that HAXM can't be installed because I either have Hyper-V on or SVM is off.

Comment: Haxm does not support AMD cpus, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825504/failed-to-install-haxm-for-android-studio-amd/65703510#65703510.

Answer (score 0):

If you boot Windows with HyperV enabled, it will then permanently have exclusive access to hardware virtualization, regardless of any HyperV guests actually running. You need to entirely disable HyperV through the Windows Features function, reboot, and then you should be fine. It's a kinda weird quirk of HyperV.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the screenshot of that too. But Windows Features has hyper V and all it's branches disabled too. I also rebooted multiple times to double-check. Thanks for the help though. I guess it's just a bug.